# Debian simple-scan inoperative shortcuts

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, scanner

I installed [Emmabuntus](https://emmabuntus.org/) (Debian Buster based) on an ordinosaur computer with LXQt as DE. The **simple-scan** application v3.30.1.1 is installed by default and works, but the supposed shortcuts **ctrl + f** and **ctrl + m** that greatly simplify the scanning task are ineffective. Nothing is happening. The shortcuts seem to be "hard-coded" in the application (they are given from the "Keyboard shortcuts" menu and I couldn't find a config file).

How do I know if the problem is with the application itself or if the system or DE (or whatever) intercepts the shortcut before the application ?

How to make these shortcuts effective ?

Thank you in advance for your expert advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer to myself because I found the solution many weeks ago. The problem has nothing to do with DE or distro or whatever but it is implicit to the application simple-scan itself. We must just run the command by preceding an environment variable like this command `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=XFCE simple-scan` so ctrl+f shortkey and others are again available ([source](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=784096#c4))

So my problem is resolved :)